# why i have this error with adactivity declared in androidmanifest.xml with configchanges

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-manifest, admob

**Android 2.1**

**googleAdmobAdsAsdk6.2.1.jar**

my problem show when i test my ads in my app --> error --> you must have adactivity declared in androidmanifest.xml with configchanges

i'm try to add full activity like this

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

**get to me this error**

```
    error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
   or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
   distributed with this work for additional information
   regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
   to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
   "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
   with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
   software distributed under the License is distributed on an
   "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
   KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
   specific language governing permissions and limitations
   under the License.
    -->
    <manifest 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
  package="com.afrogfx.VerbTenses" 
  android:versionName="1.1" 
  android:versionCode="5" >

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />



<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:allowBackup="true" >



    <activity android:name="VerbTenses" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <!-- AdMobActivity definition -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|"/>

</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    </manifest>
```

**mainactivity.java**

```
    /*
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
   or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
   distributed with this work for additional information
   regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
   to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
   "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
   with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
   software distributed under the License is distributed on an
   "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
   KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
   specific language governing permissions and limitations
   under the License.
    */

    package com.afrogfx.VerbTenses;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import com.google.ads.*;

    import org.apache.cordova.*;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public class VerbTenses extends DroidGap
    {
private static final String AdMob_Ad_Unit = "a150d4ba1fd9a78";
private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/overview.html");

    //admob
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit_HERE); 
    super.root.addView(adView); 
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    //request.setTesting(false);
    adView.loadAd(request);
}
    }
```

**Layout Main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat**

```
    01-06 17:15:48.105: I/dalvikvm(283): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.<init>, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.<init>
    01-06 17:15:48.105: W/dalvikvm(283): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 417: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
    01-06 17:15:48.105: D/dalvikvm(283): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0001
    01-06 17:15:48.105: D/dalvikvm(283): VFY: dead code 0x0004-005b in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
    01-06 17:15:48.395: I/CordovaLog(283): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
    01-06 17:15:48.395: I/CordovaLog(283): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
    01-06 17:15:48.436: D/CordovaLog(283): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
    01-06 17:15:48.436: I/CordovaLog(283): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
    01-06 17:15:48.436: D/CordovaLog(283): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
    01-06 17:15:48.505: D/JsMessageQueue(283): Set native->JS mode to 2
    01-06 17:15:48.505: I/CordovaWebView(283): Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge since Android version is old.
    01-06 17:15:48.525: D/DroidGap(283): DroidGap.init()
    01-06 17:15:48.544: D/CordovaWebView(283): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/overview.html)
    01-06 17:15:48.544: D/PluginManager(283): init()
    01-06 17:15:48.614: D/CordovaWebView(283): >>> loadUrlNow()
    01-06 17:15:48.645: E/Ads(283): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenLayout.
    01-06 17:15:48.645: E/Ads(283): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include uiMode.
    01-06 17:15:48.645: E/Ads(283): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenSize.
    01-06 17:15:48.654: E/Ads(283): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include smallestScreenSize.
    01-06 17:15:48.654: E/Ads(283): You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges.
    01-06 17:15:49.284: D/DroidGap(283): Resuming the App
    01-06 17:15:49.435: D/dalvikvm(283): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3187 objects / 290448 bytes in 101ms
    01-06 17:15:49.515: D/DroidGap(283): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/overview.html)
    01-06 17:15:49.585: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(283): Ignore this event
    01-06 17:15:49.704: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(283): Ignore this event
    01-06 17:15:50.444: D/dalvikvm(283): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1079 objects / 131560 bytes in 120ms
    01-06 17:15:50.465: D/webviewglue(283): nativeDestroy view: 0x26b710
    01-06 17:15:57.385: D/CordovaLog(283): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setpagenum
    01-06 17:15:57.385: D/CordovaLog(283): file:///android_asset/www/overview.html: Line 35 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setpagenum
    01-06 17:15:57.385: E/Web Console(283): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setpagenum at file:///android_asset/www/overview.html:35
    01-06 17:15:57.396: D/Cordova(283): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/overview.html)
    01-06 17:15:57.396: D/DroidGap(283): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
    01-06 17:15:57.405: D/DroidGap(283): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/overview.html)
    01-06 17:15:59.479: D/DroidGap(283): onMessage(spinner,stop)
```

Answer (score 1):

By mistake you have added one **"|"** extra in **android:configChanges** thats why it is reading as String so please remove that.

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|"/>
```

Please remove this **"|"** last char, and write like..

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

After doing this clean the project, Hope it will work for you..:)

Comment: thank you but still have this error you must have adactivity declared in androidmanifest.xml with configchanges

Answer (score 1):

You need to have all 7 items in:

1. keyboard
2. keyboardHidden
3. orientation
4. screenLayout
5. uiMode
6. screenSize
7. smallestScreenSize

#### For example:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change the `minSdkVersion=17` in your `Manifest` file.

Comment: I change my code to this but still give me error in ad-activity  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>`

Comment: I said that you try to change the `minSdkVersion=17`. I think you have not got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the project target in your `project.properties` file to

`# Project target.`

`target=android-13`

Comment: i do it but still have this error you must have adactivity declared in androidmanifest.xml with configchanges